# Signal assignment type

Tags: vhdl, signal, state-machines

What is the meaning of "combinational assignment" and "registered assignment" to signals? In particular what are the differences between these two types of assignments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, the difference boils down to whether the signal gets assigned on a clock edge or not.

Combinational code, like 
    A <= B + 1
would have A being assigned B+1 "immediately," whereas

```
    process(clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            A <= B + 1;
        end if;
    end process;
```

would result in A being assigned B+1 only on a rising clock edge.  With code like this, other blocks can use the value of A being guaranteed that its value will be stable and unchanging after a clock edge.

Registers, or clock gating in general I suppose, are really what make designs of any complication possible.  You create a pipeline of operations by putting a register at the border between operations.  For example, the input operands to an ALU must be stable - in a register- so that the ALU can execute properly, and the result of the ALU's execution should be in a register so that whatever block uses it does not 'see' the changing values inside the ALU as the calculations take place, but only the stable last result.

Comment: Question: Is a transparent latch considered combinatorial or registered?

Comment: Yes and no - the input to a transparent latch propagates directly to the output, not on a clock edge.  But the addition of an enable signal could make the latch be controlled on a clock edge, ie, opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Assignments in VHDL are neighter specified as registered or combinatorial. In VHDL the actual assignment type (the type of RTL logic generated) is just inferred.

Registers in VHDL are created explicitly by assigning a signal on a clock edge, though just because a process has a clock it does not mean all signals in that block will be assigned on every edge.

Also registers can be inferred without a clock,  if some path through a process does not assign a signal, then VHDL assumes you meant to latch that signal between successive passes. This is called an inferred latch (and should be avoided).

VHDL does not know about the technology that you are going to be using.  It does not know whether your synthisis engine can generate T,D,JK,SR, or any other sort of latch. For that reason it just suggests a latch, it is up to the synthisis enging to decide which latch fits the bill or if it is simply impossible.  Similarlay the fitter might say that a particular latch requested by the synthisis enging is not available or there are no enough of them.